# grouped_collection_select with particular objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, collections

I have a grouped_collection_select with some Products (linked to a category):

```
<%= c.grouped_collection_select :product_id, @categories, :products, :name, :id, :name, :include_blank => true %>
```

But I just want some products which have a boolean to "true", is it possible to specify this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically calling a method for an instance of each parent object in the grouped select. So if you have an instance method for the parent object (a Category) that corresponds to the products you need, you can call it in the helper.  Something like this:

```
Class Category
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products

  def target_products
    #return a collection here that corresponds to what you're looking for based on
    #your criteria in the associated product(s) object. For example:
    self.products.active  #where active is a named scope in Product for what you're looking for.
    #You could also add an AR macro method with a condition etc. Basically any thing that 
    #will respond to category.target_products in the end.
  end

end
```

Then use this method in your grouped_collection_select.

```
<%= c.grouped_collection_select :product_id, @categories, :target_products, :name, :id, :name, :include_blank => true %>
```

Comment: Thanks A LOT, I was trying this since a long time.

Comment: No prob. Sorry for the initial confusion on the initial answer.

Comment: what if we want to pass some parameters to :target_products method. My question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581359/grouped-collection-select-custom-method, would you please help.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you would want to build your collection based on that criteria. Meaning, @categories would only contain those categories with the products that meet your condition.

*(I'm making some assumptions about your schema but something like this should work:)*

```
@categories = Category.where("products.some_attribute = ?", true).joins(:products)
```

Comment: This was already what I made but the problem is that ALL the products are here for this category, even those which are "false"...

Comment: Hm. Sounds like you're doing something wrong. The resulting query that's built from this code would only return those products with "some_attribute" as true (or 1). Can you post your code that sets @category?

Comment: The code you wrote is "give me only categories with some products with attribut equals to true. But grouped_collection_select will take all the products from those categories ! So yes I only have categories with at least one product 'true', but also with 'false' because it is never precised in grouped_collection_select.

Comment: One of us is confused. The select can only build itself based on what it's provided with. So, if the query selects only those products (and associated categories) that have the flag set to 'true' it can not possibly contain those that are false. Can you please show me how @categories is being set?!

Comment: I don't understand what you want me to show you, @categories is set with your code "@categories = Category.where("products.some_attribute = ?", true).joins(:products)" and then I use the grouped_collection_select in my first post.

Comment: your code didn't build @categories with products, it only returns categories which have a product to true. So when grouped_collection_select use this categorie, it show ALL the products of this category. There is maybe something more useful than grouped_collection_select ?

Comment: Ah okay, I understand the problem now.  You can add an instance method to your Category class which would return the collection of products that meet your criteria.  Then use that :method_name in the grouped_collection_select. I'll add another answer explaining this.